# Saving Data Privately On Device

Tags: android

I have files that I want to save so they are not accessible by other applications and that are safe from updates (won't be deleted).

**My Problem**

I am not sure where to save them. I know that I can save them in the data directory using the below code to get the path but I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
Environment.getDataDirectory();
```

**My Question**

Is the applications data directory the correct place to store my data or is it meant just for system data?

If it isn't the correct place, could you suggest where is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean "not accessible"?  Give me your app, and I'll have the files in 30 seconds with Root Explorer.

Comment: @Simon I mean the average user can't get at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you have already come across this

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

In that you see Internal storage is usually a methodology which helps in achieving what you asked for. Yes you can use the function which you have shown

or

`(OWNERACTIVITY).getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`

should give you the location where data for the application gets stored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I overlooked the 'getFilesDir();' totally my fualt. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

If you are keeping files in SD card, all applications (with android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) can access the data. The best place is is keep them in your data directory. Your application can access the data as long as your package name and certificate is not changed. If you want to store some files like images and audio, you can store them in SD card in a directory with .nomedia in it. But if you want to keep some data files, checksums etc, it is better to keep them in data directory. Even if you update your application, you should still be able to access it.

YOu can read more  [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)